# Use Node.js as WebRTC peer - Decode frames on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I would like to:

1. Setup Node.js as a WebRTC peer (ex. that web browser can connect to)
2. Decode video frames in real-time on server side (ex. streamed from browser's webcam)

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I have seen many similar questions, but have not encountered any obvious answers.

Is this possible with just Node, or must one use a gateway such as Janus as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the answer was to run a Janus server alongside Node. A custom plugin was written for Janus to handle the WebRTC frames and pass them to my node server as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you require realtime video: implementing DTLS, SRTP and codec handling is not trivial.

If you don't require realtime, you might want to give the [MediaStreamRecorder API](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/) a try and send the data from the ondataavailable event via websocket to your node server.
Or capture from a canvas which is shown [here](https://github.com/legastero/jingle-interop-demos/blob/gh-pages/stanzaio/index.html#L158-L184) and send that to the server as a jpg image.

Comment: Unfortunately I need real-time access to the stream (edited original question to clarify). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: you might want to try https://github.com/ibc/mediasoup -- written in a mix of node and c++